# Wso2 identity server apllication access through datastore user

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server, identity-management

I have an application that has its own database store where username and password are stores that these users can access this application i want to authenticate identity server with this user store

is it possible that I integrate this database store to the identity server so that when the user login in identity server through this database username and password then he can access the application without authorization because he already login through this application database store username and password. in wso2 identity server

Answer (score 1):

If your application supports any standard protocols like SAML, OIDC etc. you can configure the third-party application as a Federated IDP. If not, you can write a [Custom Userstore Manager](https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/references/extend/write-a-custom-user-store-manager/) if you want to plug a custom user store.

Answer (score 1):

You can directly connect your user store to the WSO2 Identity Server if it's either one of the following.

1. LDAP
2. LDAP AD
3. AD
4. JDBC

Please see [here](https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/references/concepts/user-management/userstores/).

If your user store is not one of the above, you can still connect it by writing a custom user store manager as said by @ycr above.